# R - Number Rounding error when copying to Row

Tags: r, dataframe, rounding, int64

Below is how I created an empty data frame I intend to populate 1 row at a time from a data source.

```
numTweets=31
finalDataFrame = as.data.frame( matrix(NA, numTweets-1, 23), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)        
names(finalDataFrame) = c( "TweetID", "TweetTime", "Text", "Source",
                        "UserID", "Username", "Screenname", "FollowerCount", "FriendCount",
                        "Location", "Latitude", "Longitude", "ReplyTweetID", "ReplyUserID", 
                        "ReplyScreenname", "RetweetID", "RetweetCreated", "RetweetUsername",
                        "RetweetScreename", "RetweetLocation", "RetweetFollowers", "RetweetFriends",
                        "RetweetSource" )
```

An example of a row I am inserting is below as well

```
print( thisRow, row.names=FALSE )
TweetID                      TweetTime                                                                                                                                     Text
 877010425019158529 Tue Jun 20 03:49:14 +0000 2017 @OmniDestiny I would recommend trying to find the facebook group for evergreen because i think their school facebook page got shut down.
                                                             Source             UserID Username Screenname FollowerCount FriendCount     Location Latitude Longitude       ReplyTweetID ReplyUserID ReplyScreenname RetweetID
 <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a> 843603187298779137   Albert   HellhoyZ             4          72 Bellevue, WA        0         0 876742560328417281  4726147296     OmniDestiny        NA
 RetweetCreated RetweetUsername RetweetScreename RetweetLocation RetweetFollowers RetweetFriends RetweetSource
             NA              NA               NA              NA               NA             NA            NA
```

So, this row looks perfectly fine, and the data frame I have created to store it in looks fine.  However, when I try to copy it in...

```
## Z minus 1 since we started our loop at 2
finalDataFrame[z-1, ] = thisRow
```

Many values get weird.  For example, thisRow displays the ReplyTweetID value (an int64 value) perfectly as 876742560328417281, but when I look at it in R in the finalDataFrame....

```
finalDataFrame[1, "ReplyTweetID" ]
[1] 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046816189162956993
>
```

I'm not sure what can cause this drastic change.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm pretty sure it has to be due to the value being an int64, and the Matrix not liking that.  However, is there a way to prep the Matrix for that?  I can alternatively do toString( IDVALUEHERE ) when I am making "thisRow" in the first place, but that seems like it shouldn't be necessary.